# Recommendation: Scrape data from basic html table (external url) into another html table

Tags: web-scraping

I'd love to get your recommendations for scraping data from a simple html table into my own html table. No need to extract into formats like .csv and so on. When I view my table I want the external data (from diff url) to load. What tool would you recommend me? I find it as pretty straightforward do you think is it possible to do this within JavaScript included in html file?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is possible within JavaScript included in HTML file, this depends on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy of the source site. If fetching from an outer origin is forbidden, you can try a tool like [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt UPDATE: CORS of the source site is blocking it. Thanks for the puppeteer recommendation.